# How can I return the response of the Axios Post in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a little problem.

I have a post function in ReactJS (totally working). I wanna have the response of it outside this function, right where I called it. How can I do that?

```
async function confereInicial(idAluno,idDisciplina){

  return await Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/check",{
      idAluno: idAluno,
      idDisciplina: idDisciplina}).then((response)=> {
  });

}

//please ignore the way I call and read my function. it's confusing but I just wanna console.log the data outside my function. ignore the map etc

  return (
    <div>

              {
              
              dados.state.nodesPadrao.map(p => {
                confereInicial(1,p.id).then(data => console.log(data)); //how should I do that?




app.post("/api/check",(req,res) => {

    const idAluno = req.body.idAluno;
    const idDisciplina = req.body.idDisciplina;

    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM `disciplinas_feitas` WHERE id_aluno = ? AND id_disciplina = ?;"
    db.query(sqlSelect,[idAluno,idDisciplina],(err,result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });

});
```

may someone please help me?
[image]

Comment: running logic in react return or render statement isn't ideal

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? What's the problem with the current code? What have you tried so far?
Also, as to `please ignore the way I call and read my function` – cleaning up your example code helps future readers.

Comment: are these variables perhaps in a foreign language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```js
function confereInicial(idAluno,idDisciplina) {
  return Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/check",{
      idAluno: idAluno,
      idDisciplina: idDisciplina
  });
}
```

This will return a Promise, so `confereInicial(1, p.id).then(response => console.log(response.data))` should work.

Comment: but can I put this confereInicial(1, p.id).then(data => console.log(data)) into a variable? ps.: I think stack overflow deleted my comment but I said 'it f c k e n worked!!! thank you'

Comment: I would still appreciate your answer.. The answer below this one helped me but I think your way is better

Comment: I read your question and comments again, but I'm really confused by what you're trying to accomplish and what exactly is the problem. Sorry! The only thing I see is that when you're logging the response, it logs the whole Axios Response object, but what we want is only the `response.data` – I edited my answer to reflect that. You need to do that also when you follow @SebMaz93's answer.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you and you can put it into a variable, you don't need to put it into a map function when you are not returning a valid JSX element from it.

```
const dataArray = [];

  async function confereInicial(idAluno, idDisciplina) {
    return axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/check", {
      idAluno: idAluno,
      idDisciplina: idDisciplina
    });
  }

  const getData = () => {
    dados.state.nodesPadrao.forEach(async (p) => {
      const i = await confereInicial(1, p.id);
      console.log("ITEM", i);
      dataArray.push(i);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData(); // can be called onClick or anywhere you want (make sure don't call on each re-render)
  }, []);

  console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: would you please show me how to put into a variable, not a state?

Comment: @PauloHenrique I've updated to code now to push into variable array, not state.

Comment: can't I simplify this and do something like this?
async function confereInicial(idAluno,idDisciplina){

  return Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/check",{
      idAluno: idAluno,
      idDisciplina: idDisciplina});

}

const variavel = await confereInicial(1,3);

Comment: @PauloHenrique you can if you don't need the Loop, just call the push thing after the axios post resolve, but remove the return statement and assign the value into variable with await  , const data = await axios.post..... and push the data into array.

Comment: hey I editted my original post and added my post function (check). I did this: const dataArray = [];

const confereInicial = async (idAluno, idDisciplina) => {
  const data = await Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/check", {
    idAluno: idAluno,
    idDisciplina: idDisciplina
  });
  dataArray.push(data);
  console.log(dataArray);
} 
but it didnt console.log right. It printed the MESSAGE, not the RETURN (the results of my mysql command). what do I dooooooo

Comment: I also added a image of what the console.log prints

Comment: @PauloHenrique Please, try to focus your question a bit. Now there's too many parts. We can help with specific questions, like _"How to store result of API call in a variable?"_, or _"How to return results from a DB call?"_. But these shouldn't be mixed together – you should make separate SO questions. Now it seems like you're saying _"Here's my code, fix it for me"_ – that's not what this site is for. What we write here has to be useful for other members of this community too – even your question. Currently, the question is really hard to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry mate I've used this site jsut once. I'm gonna make a new post and would be really happy if you help me there. Thank you for everything here